# Word choice for hierarchical groups of data: data point → data set →?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, technical

A *data point* is a single unit of information.

A *data set* is a collection of data points (also known as a *data series*).

Is there a word for a collection of data sets?

I don't simply want to use "data sets" because of the context; it is important they look distinct at a glance.

Comment: One word used in the RDBMS space is "*catalog*".

Comment: What about a "data collection" or a "database"?  But it seems like part of your trouble is in allowing two names "set" and "series" for the same thing.  If you kept "series" as a collection of points, then "set" can be a collection of "series"

Comment: "data" is the plural of "datum", which means a single unit of information. Thus, data is a collection of datums, and a data set is a collection of collections of datums.

Comment: Relational databases would build as follows: field, record, table, database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superset is often used to refer to a set of sets, see http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superset.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, a superset is not a set of sets. A superset is a set that contains all the elements of another set. E.g. A = {1,2,3,4} is a subset of B = {1,2,3,4,5}. B is a superset of A, although it is still just a regular set.

Comment: Agreed, I was thinking more about body building.

Comment: the true context of the question is charting software

Answer (score 4):

It can also be referred to as a family of sets

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets

Answer (score 0):

In software, especially when dealing with taxonomy relations, you will often use the word `parent`. So you would talk about parent sets and child sets with points existing in the children.